Does Hilt support injection with reified generics?
I want to make my code a bit smaller, and I already tried to do this thing:
@Provides
inline fun <reified T> provideJsonAdapter(moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter()

I already have 3 @Provides functions which provides json adapters for some types. I would like to simplify my code by making function like at the top, but it doesn't work and throws error during the project's build error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] in classes which injects json adapters.

Inline functions per se shouldn't be a problem, but I don't think generics will work:

@Provides methods may not have type parameters

That's the compile error generated by KSP when I use a type parameter, it doesn't matter if it is reified or not.
This doesn't leave much room for interpretation, so I would guess you're out of luck. I haven't tried it with kapt though.
